# Regular/Daily Sign-In for an Event/Class

Tags: civievent, registration, online-registration, repeating-events, civicrm-event

I've created a **Class** for all of my attendees to register online with pretty easily, filling out all of the necessary information needed to be fully registered and in our system.

Now, how do I, or can I, have an online sign-in form for each day the class takes place and participants attend? The idea I thought of was using the aforementioned registration form as the main information collecting form for each participant's initial entry, and then creating a separate **Event** that records the bare minimum (maybe just name and email) for students to sign in each class. Would this be the best way to do this? And if so, would it make sense to then make that "Sign-in Event" a repeating event, a new "Sign-in Event" each day the class takes place, or is there a way to have a Sign-in form that is used each time, recording the participants' daily entries? Or is there some type of regular sign-in feature associated with each Event?

Hope all of this makes sense, and thanks in advance for everyone's help!